# Hide weekends on WPF toolkit chart

Tags: wpf, charts, finance, weekend

I am making a small app that plots financial price data and since the finance markets are closed on the weekends, I have no data for those days. By default the chart, found in the new WPF Toolkit, shows a large gap between Friday and following Monday and this behaviour is not acceptable. I am trying to figure out a way to "hide" the weekend gaps but can't seem to find any good solutions. So far, I figured that I would have to overload the standard `DateTime` struct (how?) which will be able to recognize and skip weekends and holidays. I am looking for suggestions and/or pointers before I start down that slippery slope.

Some more details:

I am given a wide range of data - currently daily closing prices on NYSE. I am using the `DayTimeAxis` to plot the independent variable of `LineSeries` which is of type `DateTime`. It currently simply plots all the prices, one day at a time - and that's where the devil is, it shows wider gaps due to lack of data for Saturdays and Sundays and some major holidays.

I will eventually have to show more detailed (hourly, minute) chart once data becomes available, but the problem will remain if the user will want to view hourly data for some Friday and the following Monday.

Comment: It would help if you specified what interval for the inpendendent value you are ploting (every hour, close of day, something else)? Also what series type are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much playing around with various options, I ended up using the CategoryAxis instead of DateTimeAxis. It treats each day as a category without inferring the relationship between the days.

The data can still be kept as DateTime objects for any necessary calculations and you just have to worry about the ToString (that's what CategoryAxis to label each category). Or just throw them all in as strings - technically calculations are done on the data points, not the array of dates so not much of a loss here...

Answer (score 1):

If you will plot candlestick or ohlc you can't go with toolkit (you can but it will be VERY unpleasant) if you are open to use component use visifire's the one you may go.  if you can't figure it out with that send a sample code please.

Answer (score 0):

Completely off the top of my head, so I'm not sure how feasible this would be, but could you possibly set up a value converter on the Width property of the data point that would return "Auto" on a weekday and 0 for a weekend?